# Initial Log in to rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I have successfully installed and configured devise with an admin model with "option 1" of [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role) instruction.

After installing rails_admin and visiting localhost:3000/admin I meet a login page wich is asking for an email and password. Since I have not set an admin email/password I am essentially locked out of rails_admin.

How can I register an admin email/password with rails_admin?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, I installed rails-admin on an Admin model. Should I have installed rails-admin on the Users model If I want to track users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run on command prompt: `rake db:seed` then you can access with email `admin@admin.com` and password: "`administrator`".

Comment: Do I need to modify the seeds.rb file?

Comment: When I ran rake db:seed I got an error because I have two migrations with the same name (20130117211922_devise_create_admins.rb and 20130117225418_devise_create_admins.rb) is it safe to delete a migration in general?

Comment: mograte your devise related model

Comment: running rake db:seed did not allow "admin@admin.com/administrator" to work. Are you sure I should not modify the seeds.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Ganeshkunwar advice and ran rake db:seed but added the following to my seeds.rb

```
admin_model     = RailsAdmin::AbstractModel.new(Admin)
admin_model.new(:email => '****@****.com', :password => '****', :password_confirmation => '****').save
```

Thanks SO!